# `italic` comments in the global inbox

Tags: support, comments, user-interface, global-inbox

I just received a comment on an answer that started out with italicized text.

[Writing to a section in an INI file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21921026/writing-to-a-section-in-an-ini-file/21928367?noredirect=1#comment33241477_21928367)

> *It will only replace anything up to the last valid key/value pair. Anything else beyond will be left as is.* This explains the behavior...

In the global inbox, the word `italic` is shown in the message.  I imagine it will do something similar to `bold` or `code` comments.  I'm also seeing the same behavior in the Android app so it's not specific to the top-bar global inbox but apparently with how the notification text is generated.

[image]

I'm not sure if this applies only to comments or answers, bounties or other non-system inbox notifications with user text.

Not really a problem for me but thought it was worth a mention.  Bug?

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if the commenter initially wrote the comment with the word `italic` or did `<italic>...` then edited it to be correct. AFAIK, the inbox will show the original comment but not show any edits (and the comment was edited).

Comment: Could someone do me a favor and write a comment here starting with `_italic text_`, `**bold text**`, and `\`code\` text`? Just want to test my theory.

Comment: _TEST_ in italics. **TEST** in bold. `TEST` in code.

Comment: @ObliviousSage: looks like it was edited out. Your comment just showed the text. http://i.stack.imgur.com/s79E9.png

Answer (score 1):

All HTML is stripped from the comment excerpts, always. This includes any italic, bold, code, links, etc. Comments cannot have custom HTML, so all `<` and `>` characters get encoded to begin with. It's as simple as running a `strip_html` function on the comment.

If you want, go through your Stack Exchange inbox. You'll never find a comment with any sort of formatting on it. ;)

Comment: I guess my theory on it being edited was correct.  @ObliviousSage's comment to me did not have any of the text I mentioned. http://i.stack.imgur.com/s79E9.png